# How can net potential energy for a charged particle be 0 but still have a net electric field

Tags: electric-fields, potential, potential-energy

[image]Im studying charged particle and i recently came up with a question that stated that a charge was released from a position in which had no electric potential but however accelerated due to a electric field, this puzzles me as the question later said that the after the particle accelerated it came to a stop infinity far away and there must be a force acting in the opposite direction for this to happen. How can this be true why does it stop and why does it have 0 energy at the end of its journey and what is this force that makes it come to a stop?

[image]

Comment: Are you aware that the energy is only defined up to a constant and that we often choose this constant such that the energy becomes zero at infinity?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can the electric potential be zero at a point where the electric field isn't, if that field can give a test charge kinetic energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/492073/how-can-the-electric-potential-be-zero-at-a-point-where-the-electric-field-isnt)